# Amazon Web Services Map-Reduce error Illegal character in path at index

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, dictionary, reduce

I am trying to run a map reduce step on my AWS cluster but get the following error. Can anyone help me understand what could be the problem? When i run the mapper code in my pycharm ide using mock data it is working as it should.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 26: s3://sg4565-nyu-2016/Final Project/weather_mapper.py
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.validateFiles(GenericOptionsParser.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.processGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:312)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.parseGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:487)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.(GenericOptionsParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.(GenericOptionsParser.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.HadoopStreaming.main(HadoopStreaming.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 26: s3://sg4565-nyu-2016/Final Project/weather_mapper.py
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2829)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3002)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3086)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3034)
    at java.net.URI.(URI.java:595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.validateFiles(GenericOptionsParser.java:395)
    ... 13 more
Command exiting with ret '1'

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space in your URL. `Final Project` is not a valid URI path.